# Send Xamarin Text labels to Firebase cloud?

Tags: android, xamarin

Trying to be more specific than my last question.

In Xamarin studio, how would I go about being able send information from some text labels that the user puts in into Firebase Cloud Messaging system? The gist is that the user will input their text, and based on prestored information on who is sending it and who it is being sent to, which will translate the information into the firebase textboxes as if it was written on the site itself.

Unfortunately I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do such a thing, if its even possible.

Is anyone able to give me some point in the right direction?

Comment: do you not understand how to get the user input from the label?  Or do you not understand how to send data to Firebase using their API?

Comment: How to send the data specifically to something like firebase, I cant seem to figure out how to do that specifically.

Comment: https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin